# convert xmlGregorianCalendar to Date and reverse

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, jpa, xmlgregoriancalendar

i all, i have a spring boot application. what i want in specific is to convert a class (that have nestet object field) in his corrispective entity. example:

```
 public class example{
String string;
ObjectExample object;
}
public class ObjectExample{
String oneString;
XMLGregorianCalendar date;
}
```

this 2 object are also marked in another package as entities, but ovviusly in the ObjectExampleEntity i have Date date instead XMLGregorianCalendar, like this with the example

@Entity

```
public class example{
String string;
ObjectExample object;
}
```

@Entity

```
public class ObjectExample{
String oneString;
Date date;
}
```

because i have a big model and big entity (this above is only an example) with a lot of nested classes , i use dozer to convert from the model to the class.
consider for example that the repository jpa is only created for the father example class.
i want to know how i can with dozer convert from Date (entity) to XMLGregorianCalendar (model) and reverse. the model and the entity,i repeat are equal. the only difference is the type of the date. thanks

Comment: FYI, both `Date` and `XMLGregorianCalendar` classes are part of the terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: ok but when i try to convert from one to the other with dozer i need to indicate how to convert from XMLGregorianCalendar to Date or Time

Comment: i can't change XMLGregorianCalendar type because my models are generated with a wsdl pre-defined by other. and i have to follow this rule filed

Comment: What do you `XMLGregorianCalendar` objects look like? `XMLGregorianCalendar` supports undefined fields, so an object may for example have or not have date, have or not have time of day and have or not have UTC offset.

Comment: Partially a duplicate of [Fetching Date from XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204642/fetching-date-from-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming:

- Since your variable is named `date` it contains a calendar date (without time of day).
- You are tied to `XMLGregorianCalendar` because of a WSDL outside your control, but you can change type on the entity side.

Based on these assumptions I recommend `LocalDate` on the entity side. It’s part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and represents exactly a date without time of day. The `Date` class that you used is poorly designed, long outdated and not recommended. Also despite the name a `Date` never represented a date, but a point in time.

There are more options. I am presenting three.

### Option 1: transfer individual fields

From `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `LocalDate`:

```
    DatatypeFactory xmlFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    XMLGregorianCalendar wsDate = xmlFactory
            .newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(2019, DatatypeConstants.MARCH, 30,
                    DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);

    // Validate
    if ((wsDate.getHour() != 0 && wsDate.getHour() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)
            || (wsDate.getMinute() != 0 && wsDate.getMinute() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)
            || (wsDate.getSecond() != 0 && wsDate.getSecond() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)
            || (wsDate.getMillisecond() != 0 && wsDate.getMillisecond() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)) {
        System.out.println("Warning: time of day will be lost in conversion");
    }
    if (wsDate.getTimezone() != DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) {
        System.out.println("Warning: UTC offset will be lost in conversion");
    }

    // Convert
    LocalDate entityDate = LocalDate.of(wsDate.getYear(), wsDate.getMonth(), wsDate.getDay());
    System.out.println(entityDate);
```

The output is in this case:

> 2019-03-30

From `LocalDate` to `XMLGregorianCalendar`:

```
    LocalDate entityDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 31);

    XMLGregorianCalendar wsDate = xmlFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(
            entityDate.getYear(),
            entityDate.getMonthValue(),
            entityDate.getDayOfMonth(),
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    System.out.println(wsDate);
```

> 2019-03-31

Advantage of this way: It’s pretty straightforward. Disadvantage: You and your reader need to take care that the fields are mentioned in the right order.

### Option 2: convert via strings

```
    // Validate as before

    // Convert
    LocalDate entityDate = LocalDate.parse(wsDate.toXMLFormat());
```

Result is as before.

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar wsDate
            = xmlFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(entityDate.toString());
```

Advantage: it’s brief, and there’s no surprise that the results are correct. Disadvantage: To me it feels like a waste to format into a string only to parse it back.

### Option 3: convert via `GregorianCalendar` and `ZonedDateTime`

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = wsDate.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime();

    // Validate
    if (! zdt.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIN)) {
        System.out.println("Warning: time of day will be lost in conversion");
    }
    if (! zdt.getZone().equals(ZoneId.systemDefault())) {
        System.out.println("Warning: UTC offset will be lost in conversion");
    }

    // Finish conversion
    LocalDate entityDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

And the other way:

```
    // It doesn’t matter which time zone we pick
    // since we are discarding it after conversion anyway
    ZonedDateTime zdt = entityDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    GregorianCalendar gCal = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
    XMLGregorianCalendar wsDate = xmlFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gCal);
    wsDate.setTime(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED,
            DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    wsDate.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

The validation I present here is a bit simpler but also not quite so strict. If you want strict validation, you can just use the validation from before.

Advantages: I think it’s the official way; at least it uses the conversion methods offered. What I like is that the conversion itself is direct and brief. Disadvantage: When converting to `XMLGregorianCalendar` we need to set the unused fields to undefined manually, which makes it wordy.

### Conclusion

I have presented three options each with their pros and cons. You may also mix, of course, but using a similar conversion both ways is probably less confusing in the end.